# Is XML a web oriented programming language?

Tags: xml, protocols

Is it a common encryption protocol? is it a text based one?and is it used in web communications?

Answer (score 2):

> Is XML a web oriented programming language?

No. It isn't a programming language.

> Is it a common encryption protocol?

No.

> is it a text based one?

It is text based.

> and is it used in web communications?

Yes … among many other things.